# Retrieve error message in ssis

Tags: ssis

Is there any way to get a string variable of error message shown in Execution result tab of a package.???
Please help.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a way to log the information/warning/error messages then you can make use of SSIS logging feature.

Please refer my answer in [**this Stack Overflow question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772667/how-to-create-a-error-log-custom-error-log-inside-the-ssis-package/6155087#6155087) to understand how to configure the logging feature.

SSIS logging will capture all the messages that are shown in the `Execution Results` tab. You can also configure it to log the messages that you are interested in.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I used logging feature of a package.
Thanks Siva.

Answer (score 1):

Though this question has already answered i would like to add few points to the question being asked.

**Is there any way to get a string variable of error message shown in Execution result tab of a package.**

Assume you encountered an error in your SSIS package, now all we need to log that error into your own table (other than SSIS catalog DB's), you can create a **Execute SQL task** with the **INSERT script parameterized**. Paramerter you need to use in Parameter Mapping tab is **System::ErrorDescription**.

INSERT INTO LOG_TABLE(ID,ERROR,ERROR_TIMESTAMP) VALUES(1,**?**,GETDATE());

**Note:** You can utilize other System Variables like PackageName,MachineName etc to log into the table.

Please refer screenshot below:

[image]