# How to Insert SQL message tab output into a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I insert the message tab result of the below sql query into a `TableTest2`?

```
CREATE TABLE TableTest2 (InsertOutput VARCHAR(100))
CREATE TABLE TestTable (ID INT, msg VARCHAR(50))    
INSERT TestTable (ID, msg)
VALUES (1, 'Message 1'), (2,'Message 2')    
DROP table TestTable
```

Here's the result of running the above query:

```
(2 row(s) affected)
```

How do I insert the above result into `TableTest2`?

Comment: Just the row count specifically or all messages in general? If all messages you are out of luck through TSQL except if you do some crazy thing with `DBCC OUTPUTBUFFER`. You can access it in C# etc through `Connection.InfoMessage `

Comment: Immediately after the insert `@@ROWCOUNT` contains `2` which you can insert into an appropriate integer field

Comment: I want to insert the output on the message tab. Which on this case is:-  (2 row(s) affected)

Comment: @MartinSmith My C# knowledge is very limited. But I can run the C# code on SSIS via the script task, can you please provide me with an example code?

Comment: There is [example code here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0hee08w(v=vs.80).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) but I'm not sure whether it will be of any use in SSIS or not. According to [the answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251434/retrieve-error-message-in-ssis) SSIS already has built in functionality for that.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to capture the actual output is by using C# (or any other non-sql language) to execute the command. That can be done in a CLR extension. The tSQLt database unit testing framework contains the procedure tSQLt.CaptureOutput to capture output for testing purposes. You can see how it uses an OnInfoMessage event handler in http://sourceforge.net/p/tsqlt/code/219/tree/tSQLtCLR/tSQLtCLR/TestDatabaseFacade.cs within the executeCommand method (starting at line 64):

```
    public SqlDataReader executeCommand(SqlString Command)
    {
        infoMessage = SqlString.Null;
        connection.InfoMessage += new SqlInfoMessageEventHandler(OnInfoMessage);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.CommandText = Command.ToString();

        SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo);

        return dataReader;
    }

    protected void OnInfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs args)
    {
        if (infoMessage.IsNull)
        {
            infoMessage = "";
        }
        infoMessage += args.Message + "\r\n";
    }
```

---

If you just want to use this for testing purposes have a look at tSQLt.org The opensource tSQLt unit testing framework helps with a lot of things that are frequently encountered during automated testing.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL SERVER [@@ROWCOUNT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187316%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) return number of rows affected by an operation. You can do something like

```
DECLARE @iRec int

INSERT TestTable (ID, msg)
VALUES (1, 'Message 1'), (2,'Message 2')    

SET @iRec = @@ROWCOUNT;

INSERT TableTest2(InsertOutput) 
VALUES (CAST(@iRec as VARCHAR(10)) + ' row(s) affected')
```

Comment: @@Rowcount return the number of inserted records. But running the above query will return: **(2 row(s) affected)** on the message tab. I want to insert what is returned on the message tab. Your answer doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: The message inserted into your TableTest2 will be `2 rows(s) affected.` Feel free to add open/closed parentesses as needed. @@ROWCOUNT will do the same for SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE etc.

Comment: I can't add / close parenthesis because if the query returns an error message on the message tab then I'm screwed. I still want to insert that error message on the message tab. @YuriyGalanter

Comment: That's different then. In that case use the other solution to capture actual output. But if you need to capture SQL errors in your own code - you don't need to go to such extremes - it will be propagated to you anyway so you can catch it and log it.