# Recording error descriptions in an SSIS Data Flow (VS2008 BIDS)

Tags: error-handling, ssis, dataflowtask

I'm trying to use event handlers to log errors in my SSIS packages. Unfortunately there is no option to add event handlers to individual tasks within a data flow task; I have consequently added an event handler to the overall data flow task at the control flow level.

When an error occurs within the data flow task I would like this event handler to trigger **once**, recording the error and any kind of error description possible.

I initially set the error handler trigger to **OnError**, however this triggers multiple times (when a constituent data flow task fails, when the overall package fails, etc.). I changed to an **OnTaskFailed** trigger, however this does not appear to have a System::ErrorDescription variable available for logging.

Am I missing something? Is there no way to provide a single error message from a data flow task failure? Is this something that is fixed in future versions?

*This issue is in VS2008 BIDS*

Comment: Could you help me understand your question better? Perhaps a concrete example of where something bad is occurring and why/where you don't see the ErrorDescription

Comment: Apologies, a second read through was needed. Have edited substantially. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concise error logging using error handlers is not possible for data flow tasks in BIDS 2008.

The only options are to use direct logging within the data flow task itself (via SQL or script tasks), or record multiple error messages at the control flow level error handler.